# How to display the image from the public/storage/images in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

profile.blade.php

```
 <form action="{{route('user.profile.update',$user)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')

                <div>
                <img height="100px;" class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{$user->avatar}}">

                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="avatar">

                </div>
    </form>
```

web.php

```
Route::put('admin/users/{user}/update','UserController@update')->name('user.profile.update');
```

User.php

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value){
        return asset($value);
    }
```

UserController:

```
public function update(User $user){


        $inputs=request()->validate([

                'file'=>['file'],




                ]);


        if(request('avatar')){
           $inputs['avatar']=request('avatar')->store('images');
        }

        $user->update($inputs);

        return back();
    }
}
```

This is a profile.blade.php

[image]

How to display the image from the public/storage/images in Laravel

[image]

If I inspect the image the src is src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/dT9gvraL3HbTlHcQly96YwoSJdikNj7fVL1dsIzT.jpeg". How did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you storing image link in db? Is it with url or just name of image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are storing images with name not with url.

Now, in User.php,

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value){ 
    return asset('storage/'.$value); 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: User.php  public function getAvatarAttribute($value){
        return asset($value);
    }

Comment: How are you storing images in db? with name?

Comment: url sir example images/dT9gvraL3HbTlHcQly96YwoSJdikNj7fVL1dsIzT.jpeg

Comment: Use something like this in your accessor - ```return asset('storage/'.$value)```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I skipped some parts of your question. You need to change the path in User.php as following:

```
public function getAvatarAttribute($value){
        return asset("storage/$value");
}
```

To get accessible url for public URLs. Laravel provides [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset) helper for the same.

For example if your image is stored in

> public/storage/image/user.png

You can easily access the image like below:

> asset('storage/image/user.png') //outputs complete url to the file

Note: public folder is considered as base directory.